# Remove older backup from directory using shell command

Tags: linux, shell, unix, awk, cron

In my shell script, I am creating a backup of my folder. I am setting this activity by cronjob and the schedule keeps on changing.

It is keeping the backup with timestamp. Like for e.g :

cd /tmp/BACKUP_DIR

```
backup_06-05-2014.tar
backup_06-08-2014.tar
backup_06-10-2014.tar
```

What I want, whenever I run the script, it should keep the latest one and the previously taken backup only. And delete the remaining backups.

Like if I run the script now, it should keep

```
backup_06-10-2014.tar
backup_06-18-2014.tar
```

And delete all the other one. What `rm` command should I use ?

Comment: I'd recommend using a YYYYMMDD date format in the filename, sort ascending/descending, pick and delete the first/last one on the list.

Answer (score 6):

Try as follows:

```
rm $(ls -1t /tmp/BACKUP_DIR | tail -n +2)
```

Listing sorted by date names of files with remaining only two newest

Comment: Awesome and elegant solution!!

Comment: On my mac, I have to add one to get the right number of lines, so for the two newest i'd have to use `rm $(ls -1t /tmp/BACKUP_DIR | tail -n +3)`

Answer (score 4):

You could try deleting files older that 7 days using a find command, for example  :

```
find /tmp/BACKUP_DIR -maxdepth 1 -type f -name "backup_*.tar" -mtime +6 -exec rm -f {} \;
```

Answer (score 0):

Use

```
rm -rf `ls -lth backup_*.tar | awk '{print $NF}' | tail -n +4`
```

1. ls -lth backup_*.tar will give the sorted list of backup files (newest being at top)
2. awk '{print $NF}' will print file names and pass it to tail
3. tail -n +4 , will print file from number 3
4. At last tail's result is fed to rm to act

Another simplified method

```
rm -rf `ls -1rt backup_*.tar | tail -n +3`
```